# StackOverflowError en compilación war de proyecto con SpringTools

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, java-11

Tengo un proyecto en la versión 2.6.0 de Spring del cual necesito generar el archivo war. Al intentar hacerlo, me genera este error.

```
[[1;34mINFO[m] Scanning for projects...
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 
[[1;33mWARNING[m] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.tevology.jockeysalud.chequeosmedicos:JockeySalud-Chequeos-Backend:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for pe.gob.susalud:jr-acreditacion-susalud-logic:jar should use a variable instead of a hard-coded path //WIN3/Compartido/Jockey Salud/libs/jr-acreditacion-susalud-1.0.0.jar @ line 167, column 16
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 
[[1;33mWARNING[m] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 
[[1;33mWARNING[m] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--< [0;36mcom.tevology.jockeysalud.chequeosmedicos:JockeySalud-Chequeos-Backend[0;1m >--[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1mBuilding JockeySalud-Chequeos-Backend 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------[m
[[1;33mWARNING[m] The artifact com.lowagie:itext:jar:4.2.2 has been relocated to com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.5.6: After release 2.1.7, iText moved from the MPLicense to the AGPLicense.
            The groupId changed from com.lowagie to com.itextpdf and the artifactId from itext to itextpdf.
            See http://itextpdf.com/functionalitycomparison for more information.
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file[m [1m(install-jar-lib)[m @ [36mJockeySalud-Chequeos-Backend[0;1m ---[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] Installing C:\Users\pdelacruz\Desktop\Proyectos\Jockey Salud\JockeySalud-Chequeos-Backend\src\main\resources\lib\jr-acreditacion-susalud-1.0.0.jar to C:\Users\pdelacruz\.m2\repository\pe\gob\susalud\jr-acreditacion-susalud-logic\1.0.0\jr-acreditacion-susalud-logic-1.0.0.jar
[[1;34mINFO[m] Installing C:\Users\PDELAC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\mvninstall2796867777529617703.pom to C:\Users\pdelacruz\.m2\repository\pe\gob\susalud\jr-acreditacion-susalud-logic\1.0.0\jr-acreditacion-susalud-logic-1.0.0.pom
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources[m [1m(default-resources)[m @ [36mJockeySalud-Chequeos-Backend[0;1m ---[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[[1;34mINFO[m] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[[1;34mINFO[m] Copying 1 resource
[[1;34mINFO[m] Copying 122 resources
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile[m [1m(default-compile)[m @ [36mJockeySalud-Chequeos-Backend[0;1m ---[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[[1;34mINFO[m] Compiling 500 source files to C:\Users\pdelacruz\Desktop\Proyectos\Jockey Salud\JockeySalud-Chequeos-Backend\target\classes
An exception has occurred in the compiler (17.0.4.1). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program, the following diagnostic, and the parameters passed to the Java compiler in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Scope.getSymbolsByName(Scope.java:107)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Scope.getSymbolsByName(Scope.java:93)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findVar(Resolve.java:1490)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findIdentInternal(Resolve.java:2410)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findIdent(Resolve.java:2402)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.resolveIdent(Resolve.java:2685)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitIdent(Attr.java:4184)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCIdent.accept(JCTree.java:2584)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:4269)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.ArgumentAttr.visitTree(ArgumentAttr.java:207)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$Visitor.visitSelect(JCTree.java:3449)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.ArgumentAttr.attribArg(ArgumentAttr.java:197)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:675)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribArgs(Attr.java:778)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:2558)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1797)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:4269)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:2567)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1797)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:4269)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:2567)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1797)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:4269)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:2567)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1797)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:4269)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:2567)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1797)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:4269)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:2567)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1797)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:4269)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:2567)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1797)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:4269)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:2567)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1797)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:4269)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:2567)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1797)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:4269)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:2567)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1797)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:4269)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:2567)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1797)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:4269)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:2567)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1797)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:4269)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:2567)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1797)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:4269)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:2567)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1797)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:4269)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:2567)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1797)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:4269)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:2567)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1797)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:4269)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:2567)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1797)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:4269)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:677)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:2567)
[[1;34mINFO[m] -------------------------------------------------------------
[[1;31mERROR[m] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[[1;34mINFO[m] -------------------------------------------------------------
[[1;31mERROR[m] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[[1;34mINFO[m] 1 error
[[1;34mINFO[m] -------------------------------------------------------------
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1;31mBUILD FAILURE[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] Total time:  14.610 s
[[1;34mINFO[m] Finished at: 2022-12-27T09:19:51-05:00
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] Failed to execute goal [32morg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile[m [1m(default-compile)[m on project [36mJockeySalud-Chequeos-Backend[m: [1;31mCompilation failure[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31mAn unknown compilation problem occurred[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] -> [1m[Help 1][m
[[1;31mERROR[m] 
[[1;31mERROR[m] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the [1m-e[m switch.
[[1;31mERROR[m] Re-run Maven using the [1m-X[m switch to enable full debug logging.
[[1;31mERROR[m] 
[[1;31mERROR[m] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1m[Help 1][m http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Este es el archivo pom.xml, en el IDE de spring, no me muestra ningún error en este archivo, tampoco en los otros paquetes del proyecto.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.tevology.jockeysalud.chequeosmedicos</groupId>
    <artifactId>JockeySalud-Chequeos-Backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JockeySalud-Chequeos-Backend</name>
    <description>Proyecto backend del modulo de chequeos de jockey salud</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.soap/javax.xml.soap-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
            <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/javase -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

</project>
```

De lo que puedo indagar, no creo que sean las dependencias, ya que anteriormente sí podía compilarlo y no he agregado más dependencias. Puedo pensar que es parte del código o alguna configuración, si a alguien más le ha pasado o me puedan ayudar con el origen del problema, sería perfecto. Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: La verdad, no, no es que se cierre el spring, sale un error al momento de compilar. Pero mientras iba probando, dejó de salir el error

Comment: lo se, me refiero a mi respuesta a esa pregunta